Exporting bathymetry data in GeoTiff format
I have some bathymetry data in WGS84 UTM15N in {x,y,z} format.
Sample:
{{660910., 3.08749*10^6, -189.586}, {660920., 3.08749*10^6, -191.11}, 
{660931.,3.08749*10^6, -193.243}, {660942., 3.08749*10^6, -195.986}, 
{660952., 3.08749*10^6, -198.73}, {660963., 3.08749*10^6, -202.082}, 
{660974., 3.08749*10^6, -205.13}, {660984., 3.08749*10^6, -207.569}, 
{660995., 3.08749*10^6, -207.569}, {661006., 3.08749*10^6, -209.702}, 
{661016., 3.08749*10^6, -210.617}, {661027., 3.08749*10^6, -211.226}, 
{661038., 3.08749*10^6, -211.531}}

How can I export the data in GeoTiff format?

The sample data seems to disagree with the UTM15N which is the projected WGS84 coordinate system for between 96°W and 90°W, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. The coordinates of the example data show a location in the Indian Ocean. Have you looked at using a GIS package like QGIS?
